# SQL with between in 2 columns statment

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

my data :

```
id    a       b     price
1     2.00    1.00  2.50
2     2.00    2.00  3.00
3     3.00    1.00  4.50
4     3.00    2.00  2.50
5     3.00    3.00  3.00
6     4.00    1.00  4.50
```

***my question is***
how get data in id 2 to 4 with sql "between" from columns a and b not columns id

```
2     2.00    2.00  3.00
3     3.00    1.00  4.50
4     3.00    2.00  2.50
```

my code sql (but not work):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM data_table  WHERE (( BETWEEN (a = 2.00, b  = 2.00 ) AND ( a = 3.00, b = 2.00  ))";
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Now I understand you want to get query result with column A and B has value between 2 and 4 right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE id BETWEEN (SELECT id FROM data_table WHERE a=2.00 AND b=2.00)  AND (SELECT id FROM data_table WHERE a=3.00 AND b=2.00)
```

Comment: the perfect answer, thanks a lot for the solution you have provided

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you making the query complex. Try this

```
Select * from data_table  where id between 2 and 4
```

Comment: not between id but from columns a and b

Comment: do u want a between 2 and 4 or b between 2 and 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BETWEEN` for both columns.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM data_table  WHERE a BETWEEN 2 AND 3 AND b BETWEEN 2 AND 4";
```

Just make Sure you have to use `AND` and `OR` in between both constraints.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from data_table where (a > 1 and a < 5 ) or (b > 1 and b < 5)
```

or you can use following with restriction

```
Select * from data_table where (a > 1 and a < 5 ) and (b > 1 and b < 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to get rows with column A and B has value between 2 and 4

try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM data_table 
WHERE (a BETWEEN 2 AND 4)
AND (b BETWEEN 2 AND 4)
```